# How to structure complexvalue fields for the SOAP api

Tags: soap-api, c#

I'm doing some preliminary research for updating a connector my company's software has (which sends data to leads in salesforce) to use a much newer version of the API. (it uses the Partner SOAP service)

Looking at the new WSDL, there are some field types that didn't exist in the old version, namely **address**, **json**, **complexvalue**, and **long**.

I'll be writing some code to properly convert/format the data the data from how it's stored in our system to how it needs to be stored in salesforce, and I'm struggling to find documentation on some of the new types, especially *complexvalue*.

*json* and *long* seem somewhat self-explanatory (json formatted data, probably passed as a string in C#, and a long integer respectively), and *address* looks to be well-documented, but *complexvalue* is throwing me for a loop.
It doesn't seem to be an option when creating a custom field for leads under object manager, and I can't find it mentioned in docs aside from [the Field page of the UI developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_field.htm) which doesn't give much explanation for how it needs to be structured under the hood.

Are there any resources I've missed? Or perhaps somewhere else that I can create fields of this type to test with? I'm pretty novice with Salesfoce, so I apologize if it is something obvious.

Even if it's not currently possible to have a *complexvalue* field in the *Lead* object type, I'd like to have a proper conversion in case that changes in future versions.

I appreciate anyone taking the time to read or respond to this. Thanks!

Comment: If you ask the Enterprise WSDL of Salesforce itself (Setup - Integrations - API - "Generate Enterprise WSDL"), "complexvalue" "can be string, picklist, reference, boolean, currency, int, double, percent, id, date, datetime, url, email". So the most generic would possibly be some text type. But if I were you, I'd not only ask what field types are on offer, but also what you're aiming at when storing this data in Salesforce. How do you want to use this data?

Comment: I see, that's interesting. Especially since sting, picklist, etc. are other field types offered in the same enumeration. 
As for what it's meant to be used for, that'll be up to each individual customer who uses our software. The mapping of fields from our system to SF is up to them, so ideally I want it to be flexible and generic, so your suggestion of some kind of text type may be the way to go. 
Do you happen know of any out-of-box object types that use a field with the ComplexValue datatype, that I can look at to get a feel for how it's used?

Comment: There is nothing like "complexvalue" that can directly be [attached to objects in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_field_types.htm&type=5). Contrary to XSD's complexType, I'm not sure  "complexvalue" is very clear at all. This is a definition of the originating system.